# Debugging with setting Xdebug and PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

i'm using PHPStorm and trying to run Xdebug according this video https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/20?autoplay=true.

First part works perfectly (https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/19?autoplay=true), but i'm stuck at second one.

Port 9000 was not working, so i changed it to 10000.

I configured PHP Web Application configuration

[image]
[image]

and after I press debug button, web is blank

[image]

and still loading and PHPStorm is waiting for incoming connection.

[image]

I have checked "can accept external connection" at PHP - Debug - Xdebug and xdebug in php.ini configured like this:

```
[XDebug]

zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.3.3/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.cli_color = 1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1

xdebug.remote_port = 10000
xdebug.remote_host= localhost
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

xdebug.remote_log="/usr/local/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.ide_key = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/usr/local/tmp/xdebug-profiler"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

I tried to validate web server with this result:

[image]

I was googling and trying solve this for 6 hours, try to help me please, i`m kind of dummy in this.

Using OS X El Capitan.

I can debug single script, but not a whole website.

When i run this directly online-chef.dev:10000, it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

"online-chef.dev" is at local virtual host.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `web server port` and `xdebug port` are 2 DIFFERENT things. You have mixed them together here. I recommend to start from scratch: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/debugger.html 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: If you will ignore that sentence "when i run this directly..", what is bad at my configuration?

Comment: You have configured xdebug to use the same 10000 port as your web server. This is plain WRONG -- it does not work that way. With your config when xdebug receives debug request it tries to connect to web server (the port) instead of IDE. And yes -- it's xdebug who connects to IDE (debug client) and not other way around.

Comment: So -- 1) leave xdebug at default TCP 9000 port (php.ini and corresponding setting in IDE, if you have changed that) 2) Make sure that you do not use "web server port" in "xdebug port" fields (and other way around). 3) Your web server port most likely needs to be a standard 80 port.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and inform you, seems hopeful!

Comment: That means:

- at php.ini have to be: xdebug.remote_port = 9000,
- at Server Configuration in PHPStorm have port 80

That should be all?

Comment: The first screenshot -- the `80` should be there (or whatever the port you are using to browse that site; 80 is default one). Not sure what else you have changed -- that's why I have suggested start from scratch (even project config -- delete `.idea` subfolder while project is closed and then use `Open` and point to project root directory)

Comment: Reinstalling xdebug helps. Thank you guys for help and explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You are tried to debug web page through xdebug. For debug javascript you need install [browser extention](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-jetbrains-chrome-extension.html). [This is manual for javascript debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/debugging-javascript.html).

For javascript debug get current extention port and enter in this place:

[image]

For XDebug i don't want always click debug button, so i simple enable listen connections. [This is manual for XDebug](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) from JetBrains.

[image]

Here is my xdebug config that working with listen connections.

```
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_host = 10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
```

So, when i need debug javascript i click debug button. When i need debug php i just put breakpoint.

First set up debugging instruments often is hard, but it's pays off.

Comment: A have already set listening to incoming connections (that cell phone icon) and extension too.

What for is remote_mode? Is it neccesary?

Comment: I updated answer. Try install right ports. http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_mode - this is about remote mode.

Comment: Thank you for help and explanation. The main thing was bulshitting with xdebug & web port. Thanks for help.